# Django retrieve data from three tables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

## Question

i am using django last version.I have three table models named like this

```
Class MCH():
Name= models.CharField()


Class Staff():
Name=models.CharField()
Mch=models.ForeignKey(MCH,,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
location=models.CharField(..)

Class Patients():   
Name=models.CharField()
Staff=models.ForeingKey(Staff,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Phone=models.CharField()
```

I want to to join the tree table using Django method  and filter data by `MCH`

## I tried this

`ServedPatients=Patients.objects. select_related(Staff__MCH='mch1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the data with:

```
ServedPatients = Patients.objects.select_related('Staff', 'Staff_Mch')
```

or if you want to filter on the name of the `MCH`, you can filter with:

```
ServedPatients = Patients.objects.filter(Staff__Mch__Name='mch1')
```

Here you obtain the `Patients` objects that have as `Staff` an `Mch` which has as name `'mch1'`. Here you however will not add the data of the `Staff` and `Mch` to the relations, you can conmbine the two with:

```
ServedPatients = Patients.objects.select_related(
    'Staff', 'Staff_Mch'
).filter(Staff__Mch__Name='mch1')
```

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `staff` instead of <s>`Staff`</s>.

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Patient` instead of <s>`Patients`</s>.